# Yarn tracking url contains hostname, not ip

Tags: hadoop-yarn

GetYarnApplicationResponse.YarnApplication.trackingUrl contains hostname, like

```
http://host54:5004/proxy/application_1522639467333_22/
```

I would like it to return ip and not a hostname, like

```
http://10.32.12.1:5004/proxy/application_1522639467333_22/`.
```

What should I do?

Comment: It is the application(such as Spark,  that runs on YARN)'s responsibility to provide the trackingUrl. So, in your case, you should see in the application how the trackingUrl is computed.

Comment: Yarn provide the trackingUrl, maybe I should read the source code.